# GIST index creation too slow on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.4, gist-index

I have a database in PostgreSQL with the following structure:

```
Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                     
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
 vessel_hash | integer               |           | not null | nextval('samplecol_vessel_hash_seq'::regclass)
 status      | character varying(50) |           |          | 
 station     | character varying(50) |           |          | 
 speed       | character varying(10) |           |          | 
 longitude   | numeric(12,8)         |           |          | 
 latitude    | numeric(12,8)         |           |          | 
 course      | character varying(50) |           |          | 
 heading     | character varying(50) |           |          | 
 timestamp   | character varying(50) |           |          | 
 the_geom    | geometry              |           |          | 
Check constraints:
    "enforce_dims_the_geom" CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2)
    "enforce_geotype_geom" CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POINT'::text OR the_geom IS NULL)
    "enforce_srid_the_geom" CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 4326)
```

The database contains ~146.000.000 records and the size of table that contains the data is:

```
public | samplecol   | table    | postgres | 31 GB      |
```

I try to create a GIST index on the geometry field `the_geom` with this command:

```
create index samplecol_the_geom_gist on samplecol using gist (the_geom);
```

but takes too long. It runs 2 hours already.

Based on this question [Slow indexing of 300GB Postgis table
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046520/slow-indexing-of-300gb-postgis-table), before index creation I execute in psql console:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET maintenance_work_mem = '1GB'; 
ALTER SYSTEM


SELCT pg_reload_conf();

pg_reload_conf 
----------------  
t 
(1 row)
```

But index creation takes too long. Does anyone know why? An how to fix this?

Comment: I have not this option unfortunately. So, you think that index creation would end up in a resonable time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you'll have to sit it out.

Apart from high `maintenance_work_mem`, there is not really a tuning option.
Increasing `max_wal_size` will help somewhat, since you will get fewer checkpoints.

If you can't live with an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock for that long, try `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`, which will be even slower, but won't block concurrent database activity.

Comment: So there is nothing that I can do. I have to wait until finish